Identify 5 pin SMD marking L1A1
Please help to identify Smd IC package SOT23-5 / SOT25 marking L1A1 and 2 pin is ground


Please refer to this question for guidelines on component identification questions. Make sure to include as many details as possible including photos of surrounding circuitry and details on what the IC function might be.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Could possibly be the Anpec APL3511B USB power distribution switch. The B variant is the SOT23-5 package.
From the datasheet we have the following pinout for the SOT23-5 package, with a matching marking code. The marking codes match the variant with 2A active high enable output, and the final letter is a date code.


